# Finding the dual of an LP

Tags: linear-programming

[image]

For the first part, Once I pivot and make $x_4,x_5$ enter the basis, we can obtain our original problem. Actually, -35 should be -62 so that we get

$$ min z = 6x_1 + 20 x_3 $$

such that

$$ x_2 + 4 x_3 \leq 10 $$
$$ 30x_1 - x_2 + 2 x_3 \leq 11 $$

do we have to assume that $x_i \geq 0$? to the problem the constraints are of the form $\leq $, does it mean that $x_i \leq 0$??

Comment: There is no constraint related to 0 is not it?

Comment: meaning the $x_i's$ are free variables?

Comment: At the simplex algorithm all $x_i$ are $\text{greater or equal}$ than $0$. If you have free variables you have to express them in terms of $x_i\geq 0$ variables.